# How do you delete one apostrophe where it is duplicated in a string?

Tags: ruby, string, apostrophe

In ruby, say I have this string: `"abc''xyz''"`

(those are 2 single quotes after `abc` and `xyz`)

Now, I am trying to find a way to make it into this string: `"abc'xyz'"`

I want to delete only one apostrophe from this string in locations where there are two apostrophes back to back. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you tried before asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String#squeeze`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze):

```
"abc''xyz''".squeeze("'")
#=> "abc'xyz'"
```

This method removes duplicates of a certain character if they are immediately after each other. It will reduce *n* characters in a row to just one.

For example, if you had the string `" '''''' "`, squeezing it would return the following:

```
" '''''' ".squeeze("'")
#=> " ' "
```

Comment: That's very handy.

Comment: Hi @athill16 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score -1):

`String#squeeze` is what you need and `gsub` is really a bad idea.

```
Benchmark.bm do |bm|

  bm.report("squeeze") do
    iterations.times do
      "e''eee''e'e''''e".squeeze("'")
    end
  end

  bm.report("gsub") do
    iterations.times do
      "e''eee''e'e''''e".gsub(/\'+/, "'")
    end
  end
end
```

And results:

```
        user       system     total     real
squeeze 6.109000   0.000000   6.109000  (  6.110040)
gsub    22.454000  0.000000   22.454000 ( 22.469204)
```